# "IOException: too many authentication attempts. Limit: 3" when using JDK HttpClient with wrong credentials

Tags: java, httpclient

I have simple code basically copy-paste from javadoc. It works well in general but in case of incorrect credentials, instead of getting proper error code I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: too many authentication attempts. Limit: 3
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.AuthenticationFilter.response(AuthenticationFilter.java:326)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseFilters(MultiExchange.java:248)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl$6(MultiExchange.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:653)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompletion.claim(CompletableFuture.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.handle(Http1Response.java:695)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.handle(Http1Response.java:621)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$Receiver.accept(Http1Response.java:612)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.tryAsyncReceive(Http1Response.java:668)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.flush(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:233)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

As I said, the code is fairly mundane:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .authenticator(new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(name.asString(), password.toCharArray());
            }
        })
        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(HttpApiUrl))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .GET()
        .build();

try {
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    if (response.statusCode() / 100 != 2) {
        logger.info("Authenticated");
        return true;
    } else {
        logger.error("Authentication failed");
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    logger.error(""Authentication failed", ex);
    return false;
}
```

I don't get why `HttpClient` uses retry logic if there is `authenticator` set (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/AuthenticationFilter.java#L324)... Without `.authenticator(new Authenticator() {}` I get nice "Not authorized" / 401. How can I disable this retry "feature"? IMHO it doesn't make much sense - if the credentials are invalid, retrying couple of times won't change it... Or at least make it return correct error code when retires fails instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the retry behaviour is given in the `AuthInfo#retryWithCredentials()` method in the same file you link to (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/AuthenticationFilter.java#L231) - it's to do with the way the creds are cached.

Thankfully, the default limit of 3 retries can be overridden by setting the `jdk.httpclient.auth.retrylimit` system property to the number of retries you'd like, e.g.:

```java
System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.auth.retrylimit", "0");
```

When that's set I now get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: too many authentication attempts. Limit: 0
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at com.hsbc.digital.testautomation.teepeereplacement.NewClient.main(NewClient.java:68)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: too many authentication attempts. Limit: 0
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.AuthenticationFilter.response(AuthenticationFilter.java:317)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseFilters(MultiExchange.java:186)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl$6(MultiExchange.java:309)
...
```

Not much of an improvement, but at least it's not retrying any more.